# Windows 10 1903 SCCM task sequence

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sccm

So, I have a working windows 10 1803 task sequence, and, I wanted to update it to 1903 so that new machines I'd upgrade would just have 1903 by default.

I downloaded the ISO form Microsoft, converted the .esd file to .wim with DISM, and then selected that as the .wim at the "apply operating system" step.

What's now happening is that everything works fine except for the Configuration Manager client not installing, which then results in all my other apps not installing since Configuration Manager didn't install first.

1903 installs just fine, the OS boots up and is domain-joined afterwards.

I sadly have absolutely no logs at all that are being recorded on the machine, nothing on the C drive as _SMS or whatever that is, and, there is also no CCM folder since CCM doesn't install.

I only have 2 items that install and they're both Microsoft C+ 2013 Redistributable x86 and x64 12.0.40660 bits.

Are these perhaps old, or, is my Configuration Manager installer on my SCCM server not up-to-date somehow? The actual I get during the task sequence is 0x80004005 which is when it fails to even install 7-zip.

The task sequence works just fine with 1803, but if I switch the WIM to 1903, the above happens.

I'm running SCCM 1902 all updates installed as of today on a host Windows 2012 R2 system.

Any thoughts of where I could look for the issue?

Thanks!

(I've even installed SupportCenter and it can't find absolutely any logs at all after the task sequence installed the OS)

I finally managed to get a hold of the ccmsetup.log file, can anyone make heads or tails of this? (in the log it seems to find those msi files afterwards and downloads them)

[image]

[I added the log file to paste bin if it helps anyone.](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/KfGizLN2)

Comment: I can't open the CCM folder on my SMS_ share even when logged in as an admin, I guess I'm not supposed to be able to by default? I guess everything does work fine for 1803, just not for 1903...

Comment: I filtered the ccmsetup.log so that only warnings and errors are shown and the other informational stuff is left out.

Comment: Apparently reading lower down in the log it did find those files and downloaded them eventually. This doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that not having a gateway defined in DHCP for clients was causing this to fail. 1803 is fine with it, 1903 isn't. I know, don't ask...